# Detach subdirectory into new repository with multiple branches

Tags: git, github, version-control

See this question: [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475)

How can we achieve the same end result, but preserving **multiple** branches from the source repository? For example if the source repository is using [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) then we may want to migrate commits that exist on both the `master` and `develop` branches. If there are any long-life `feature-` branches then these need to be migrated into the target repository too.

It appears that all examples of using `git subtree` to move a subdirectory into a new repo involve moving all the commits relating to the subdirectory from the current branch (e.g. `master`) onto a new branch. I'm trying to get all of the commits from several branches onto several new branches. Is this possible without a lot of pain?